# How do Consumer Key & Consumer Secret key work in Oauth?

Tags: api, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization

I have used several applications that use Oauth token based authentication & authorization.

What I understand is that we obtain a consumer key. Consumer keys are also known as API keys. we also need the consumer secret key. To make API calls, we also need an access token, collectively called an "oauth token".

But when calling an API we only use the access token.

What do the Consumer Key & Consumer Secret key do? How do the Consumer Key & Consumer Secret work in Oauth?

Given that I have gone through below

[Does Oauth 2.0 need consumer key/consumer secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744772/does-oauth-2-0-need-consumer-key-consumer-secret?rq=1)

[How is OAuth 2 different from OAuth 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113934/how-is-oauth-2-different-from-oauth-1?rq=1)

Comment: it may be good to indicate whether you want to address OAuth 1.0 or OAuth 2.0; most of the terminology in the question stems from OAuth 1.0 but the links point to OAuth 2.0

Comment: if so please explain using OAuth 1